# Difference between spring-boot-admin server and client

Tags: spring-boot

There are no much resources on this topic so thought to post it. Also I myself am trying to understand the different. Previously we just had only spring-boot application. So can anybody explain the difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring boot admin is nice monitoring dashboard for spring boot application. To feed data to this dashboard spring boot admin provide two approaches:

1) Using client library: client libary will send data to spring boot admin dashboard.

2) Use service discovery (eureka)

Comment: Also can you provide reference links to the point online resources ?

Comment: http://codecentric.github.io/spring-boot-admin/2.0.2/#getting-started get started with this. in few hours I will update this example to use client approach. https://github.com/jinternals/spring-cloud-stream